# Ruby on Rails grouping blog comments by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I've created a simple blog app with the usual CRUD actions. I need to group comments by date. To have something like:

```
Grouping Blog Comments <=== Blog post title

 December 19, 2013
  Create controller <==== comment
  Create View       <==== comment
  Create controller <==== comment
  Create View       <==== comment
 December 18, 2013
 draw controller <==== comment
 print View       <==== comment
  Create controller <==== comment
  Create View       <==== comment
```

**NOTE that I named my controller headlines instead of comments.**

**headlines_controller.rb**

```
class HeadlinesController < ApplicationController

    def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @headline = @post.headlines.create(params[:headline].permit(:goto, :body))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)    
  end
```

I'm sure defining archive in headlines_controller is wrong but I dont know what to do

```
  def archive
    @headlines_by_month = Headline.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC").group_by { |headline| headline.created_at.strftime("%B") }
  end
end
```

**views\headlines_headlines.html.erb**

```
<% @headlines_by_month.each do |monthname, headlines| %>
<%= monthname %>
<ul>
   <% headlines.each do |headline| %>
     <li><%= headline.body %></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

views\posts\show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

<h2>Headlines</h2>
<%= render @post.headlines %>
```

Comment: This is a confusing question tbh. I'd suggest cutting out the template details and revising that initial example.

Comment: @mahemoff I've updated the example. With the code above, it displays undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass. Hope you can help out.

Comment: Have a look at how to debug an application yourself: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: @phoet Thanks for the link. Checked it but unfortunately I still don't know what to do. I've spent the last two days reading almost every related post on stackoverflow but most talks about grouping posts and not grouping comments by date. If you can just point me out, I'll be eternally grateful